# Open and Save a New Workbook as CSV file (delimited)

Tags: excel, csv, autosave, vba

I have a workbook that has about 30 sheets. Each sheet has it's own macro. Then, a sheet called "Main Page has macros. One of them Merges all sheets, creating a new sheet combined. I need another macro that when clicked, opens a NEW workbook, copies data from Sheet "Combined" and saves it as it's own Workbook, and also, name it "Tracking Import File (todays date) .CSV"  (delimited) I can get it to do all of that except the Format of the CSV file is not the same as when I manually do it. Currently i have this macro doing this for another sheet as well, but that sheet gets saved as a normal workbook extension, which is working just fine. This is the code I have right now:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Back Order Follow up Report").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
wb.SAVEAS "S:\Production Department\Backorder Follow up reports\Back Order Follow up Report." & Format(Date, "MM.DD.YY") & ".xlsx"

*Set wb = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
wb.SAVEAS "S:\Production Department\Tracking import\Tracking Import FileTEST." & Format(Date, "MM.DD.YY") & ".csv"*

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to add a workbook if you use `WorkSheet.Copy` with no arguments.  The copied sheet will create a new workbook and that workbook will become the active workbook.

Comment: I don't know why this isn't working anymore. Literally for 2 days it worked perfect, and for no reason at all it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

There is a second, optional parameter on the wb.SaveAs method that tells Excel what format to save the file in. Merely putting ".csv" at the end of a file doesn't make it a CSV, that's only a name. To save as a CSV use:

```
wb.SAVEAS "S:\Production Department\Tracking import\Tracking Import FileTEST." & Format(Date, "MM.DD.YY") & ".csv", xlCSV
```

Comment: So this was wokring for 2 days and now I am getting a run time error 429 activeX component cannot create object. WHat does this mean? And JBARKER 2160. How would i re-rite the code using the worksheet.cop feature you wrote about?

Comment: No It's occurring on the ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1) line